# variable declaration in one line

Tags: c, variables

I thought I am allowed to declare variables in the way I did.

```
int x = y = 10;
```

However, my compiler says it is a use of undeclared identifier 'y'
Am I not allowed to declare such a way?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do - do you want to define (not *declare*) two variables - `x` and `y`, both initialized to 10?

Comment: Yes, I tried to set both as 10.

Comment: Where exactly do you think you declared the type of y?

Comment: @cheatah I thought I would be able to declare the way i did. But I notice it is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The definition above parses as:

```
int x = (y = 10);
```

This defines `x` and initializes it to the result of the expression `y=10`.  This expression assigns the value 10 to `y` and evaluates to 10.  So here `y` is expected to already exist.

Multiple variables in a definition are separated commas, and each variable may have an initializer.  So you can do this:

```
int x = 10, y = 10;
```

Or even this:

```
int x = 10, y = x;
```

The latter works because `x` exists and has been initialized at the time `y` is defined.

Comment: Even better, on two lines:  `int x = 10;`  then `int y = x;` on another line.  The only thing gained by cramming multiple variables into one line is making them harder to find when you have to go looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try this method below. It's technically two lines but you must first define the variables before assigning values to them in this case.

```
int x, y;
x = y = 10;
```